# Java, NullPointerException on using array of Objects

Tags: java, arrays, object, exception, nullpointerexception

Here is the code example. I want to create a 1 dimensional array of objects, give them values, use it in other methods, then print it out as a 2 dimensional array.

At first i want to print the starting board, but i get NullPointException when i try to loop throught the array.
The 2 dimensional array is a 6x6 matrix.

```
public class Field{
    int diceCount, playerNumber;

    //get and set methods etc.
}

public class Board{
    public Field[] board = new Field[36];

    public void boardBuilder(){
        for(int i = 0; i < board.length; i++){
            board[i] = new Field();
            //give value to the Fields      
        }
    }
}

public class IoMethods{
    public Board board = new Board();

    public void boardPrintOut(){
        int helper;
        for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < 6; j++){
                //The next line is where it gets the Exception
                helper = board.board[i*6 + j].getPlayerNumber();

                //print part
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry it's kind of late. This is just a sorter example of the code and i made a few typos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

reason is `boardBuilder()` method is not called.

Now you either call `board.boardBuilder()` before you try access it,

Or better create a constructor for Board class like -

```
Board() {
    this.boardBuilder();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You did not build the board. Do `board.boardBuilder()` before looping through the members

```
board.boardBuilder()
for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < 6; j++){
        //The next line is where it gets the Exception
        helper = board.board[i*6 + j].getPlayerNumber();
            //print part
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This line `public Field[] board = new Field[36];` creates an array of length 36 which **can** contain `Field` objects. But now all of its 36 cells are `null`. So when you try to access some `board[i]` you're accessing `null`.

**Solution**:
Write a constructor for your `Board` class and inside that write what you've written inside `boardBuilder()` or simply call `this.boardBuilder()`:

```
public Board(){
    for(int i = 0; i < board.length ; i++)
    {
        board[i] = new Field();
    }
}
```